# Iota to the power iota?

Tags: complex-numbers

As I was going through my dad's college magazine (of 1989), in the mathematics department quiz section, there was a question:

> What is $i^i$, where $i=(-1)^{1/2}$, that is, is $i^i$ a real number, an imaginary number, or undefined?

I was suddenly taken aback, I mean how can be $i$ be raised to the power $i$, I thought may be Cartesian representation helps a bit in solving it but it led me nowhere so can anyone help?

Comment: What is $i^i$? A nonexistent entity.

Comment: Yeah but the answer says it's a real number !!!!!

Comment: @Did that's the precise question......

Comment: $i \ne \iota$. ($i$ is i, $\iota$ is iota.)

Comment: This is one abuse sometimes made, even by mathematicians that should know better, that since $i=e ^{i\pi/2}$, $i^i$ should be $e^{i\cdot i\pi/2}=e^{-\pi/2}$. Only, by the same reasoning, $i=e ^{5i\pi/2}$ hence $i^i$ should also be $e^{i\cdot 5i\pi/2}=e^{-5\pi/2}$... and then chaos ensues. The real trouble is that no continuous function $z\mapsto z^i$ can be defined on the whole complex plane.

Comment: @ArnavDas Try writing $i=e^{i\pi/2}$ and think about what happens. Also think about the fact that $i=e^{5i\pi/2}$.

Comment: One can create branches of a multibranch function,  and in one of those branches, we get one of those values, @Did.  Or we could have the "function" be a set function to begin with, like the arg(Z), which returns all of the arguments possible.

Comment: @Alan We all know that, thanks. The problems I have with the multivalued function approach are that (1) I fail to see the advantages, (2) most people using it forget the "multi" part on the road.

Comment: @Did Just look at $z \mapsto i^z$ rather than $z \mapsto z^i$. Then you have entire functions (one for each choice of $\log i$). The trouble goes deeper than that power functions with non-integer exponents aren't entire.